# Open Source library for on-the-fly animation of directed acyclic graphs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, rendering, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-layout

I'm interested in finding out about open source libraries for ***on-the-fly animation*** of directed acyclic graphs.

There are many similar questions on rendering graphs, but I was unable to find one that addressed this particular need.

The specific scenario will involve rendering just a small portion of a graph as it is read, e.g. through STDIN.

Graphviz unfortunately does not seem to be up to this particular task, nor do any of the other similar libraries as far as I can tell.

Alternatively, if someone happens to know for a fact that there is no such library, that would be helpful as well, as it will be a concrete indication that it is time for me to get to work.

Edit:  I think that Dyna may meet the requirements.  I'll list it as an answer if no-one else sees or responds to this in another day or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about Gephi? http://gephi.org/